# How to access nested object within 2 arrays using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I'm having problems getting the nested car values using javascript (lodash). Here is the JSON.

```
{
 "cars":[
   {
      "nestedCars":[
         {
           "car":"Truck",
           "color":"Red",
           "type":"Honda"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "nestedCars":[
        {
           "car":"Sedan",
           "color":"Blue",
           "type":"Ford"
           
        }
     ]
   }

   ]
 }
```

The JSON response data is coming back fine.

```
 this.carLevels = response.data.cars;
```

The below code giving me back all data an I'm expecting only 2 cars (Truck and Sedan).

```
 carData() {   
   result = _.filter(this.carLevels, "nestedCars[0].car")
       }
```

I also tried nested functions but get nothing.

```
  result = this.carLevels.filter(function (a) {
    return a.nestedCars.some(function (b) {
        return b.car;
     });
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Basically I'm attempting to retrieve all car items from JSON.

Expected result:
car:"Truck"
car:"Sedan"

Comment: What is `data`? Is it JSON (i.e. still string data) or is it a real JS object? Also, note that you're almost certainly using `filter` wrong in that last block: did you mean to use `map` instead? Because filter creates a new array with every element that generated a truthy value preserved, and every element that generated a falsey value removed. All the elements in all `nestedCars` you're showing have a `car` property, so the filter does nothing.

Comment: What is `carLevels`? Where is it defined? Why are you expecting only two values if there are more in the list?

Comment: If `carLevels` is your outermost object, do you need to do something like `result = this.carLevels.cars.filter(...)`?

Comment: data is a real JS object.  I'm using Vue and I'm using axios to fetch the data.  this.carLevels is a true JS Object.  I have another method that is calling a simpler JSON object and I get the data fine.  return _.filter(this.carLevels , { type: "car" }).

Comment: Expected result:
car:"Truck" car:"Sedan"

Comment: The "expected result" isn't valid as written -- are you looking for an array of single-element objects each with `car` as its one key?  Or will just an array of the values do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for the outer array and map the `car` property of the inner arrays.

```js
const
    data = { cars: [{ nestedCars: [{ car: "Truck", color: "Red", type: "Honda" }] }, { nestedCars: [{ car: "Sedan", color: "Blue", type: "Ford" }] }] },
    cars = data.cars.flatMap(({ nestedCars }) => nestedCars.map(({ car }) => ({ car })));

console.log(cars);
```

Answer (score 1):

lodash is no longer needed for this sort of thing; native array methods have come a long way since those days.

(Note: I modified your input data a little bit to demonstrate what happens if `nestedCars` has more than one element.  If that's always a singular entry for each object in `response.data.cars`, you could simplify your data structure quite a bit without loss.)

```js
response = {
  data: {
    "cars": [{
        "nestedCars": [{
            "car": "Truck",
            "color": "Red",
            "type": "Honda"
          },
          {
            "car": "Jeep",
            "color": "Yellow",
            "type": "Jeep"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "nestedCars": [{
          "car": "Sedan",
          "color": "Blue",
          "type": "Ford"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}

this.carLevels = response.data.cars;

// ---- 

carList = this.carLevels.flatMap(el => { // step through data.cars
  return el.nestedCars.map(item => { // step through each nestedCars
    return item.car // pluck out the "car" field
  })
})

console.log({car: carList})
```

Comment: Thanks.  What is the better way to show the key car?  car: "Truck" , car:"Jeep", etc.

Comment: whatever you `return` is what you get.   But you can't have more than one of the same key in a single object, so `{car: "truck", car: "Jeep"}` isn't possible.  I modified the answer to return an array of single-element objects, but that format would be clumsy to use compared to a plain array of strings.

Comment: Never mind, that was an ugly return value.  I changed it to a better format.

Answer (score 1):

Some faster solution than `flatMap()` is `Array::reduce()` since you don't create intermediate arrays. Especially in Chrome since `flatMap()` uses iterators which 6.2x slower than usual array loops.

```js
const
    data = { cars: [{ nestedCars: [{ car: "Truck", color: "Red", type: "Honda" }] }, { nestedCars: [{ car: "Sedan", color: "Blue", type: "Ford" }] }] },
    cars = data.cars.reduce((r, { nestedCars }) => (nestedCars.forEach(({ car }) => r.push({ car })), r), []);

console.log(cars);
```

```
` Chrome/118
-----------------------------------------------------------
Alexander      1.00x  |  x10000000  160  162  163  166  169
Nina Scholz   15.25x  |   x1000000  244  248  248  250  253
-----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/119
----------------------------------------------------------
Alexander     1.00x  |  x10000000  553  583  588  595  607
Nina Scholz   1.65x  |   x1000000   91   93  106  107  114
----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const data = { cars: [{ nestedCars: [{ car: "Truck", color: "Red", type: "Honda" }] }, { nestedCars: [{ car: "Sedan", color: "Blue", type: "Ford" }] }] };

// @benchmark Nina Scholz
data.cars.flatMap(({ nestedCars }) => nestedCars.map(({ car }) => ({ car })));

// @benchmark Alexander
data.cars.reduce((r, { nestedCars }) => (nestedCars.forEach(({ car }) => r.push({ car })), r), []);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap` should do the trick:

```
let allCars = response.data.cars.flatMap(
    car => car.nestedCars.map(
        item => item.car))
```

Basically, if you only want to "extract" things, you need `map` or `flatMap`, not `filter` or `some`.